# Rails - passing parameters in a redirect_to - is session the only way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller set as the root of my app. It accepts in a parameter called uid and checks to see if the user exists. If not, I want it to redirect to the new user page and pre-populate the uid field with the uid in the parameter.

In my root_controller:

```
def index
  if params[:uid]
    @user = User.find_by_uid(params[:uid])
    if (!@user.blank?)
      # do some stuff
    else
      session[:user_id] = params[:uid]
      redirect_to(new_user_path, :notice => 'Please register as a new user')
    end
  else
    # error handling
  end
end
```

In my users_controller, GET /users/new action:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  @user.uid = session[:user_id]
  # standard respond_to stuff here
end
```

This all works fine, but is this an acceptable way to do this? I originally tried passing the uid in the redirect statement, like:

```
redirect_to(new_user_path, :notice => 'Please register as a new user', :uid => params[:uid])
```

or even testing it with:

```
redirect_to(new_user_path, :notice => 'Please register as a new user', :uid => 'ABCD')
```

but neither seemed to pass the value to users_controller...I couldn't access it using params[:uid] from that controller.

Is session a proper place to store stuff like this, or is there a better way to pass it via the redirect? Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A session is fine to store that kind of information. Depending on what you are doing with the `uid` it might actually be dangerous to allow it to be read from the URL. Imagine if the end user was malicious and started putting other user's IDs into there.

For messages that should only last until the next request Rails actually has the `flash` object which will carry it over for you.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

That said, if you want to redirect to a url and pass some params, do so like this:

```
redirect_to(new_user_path(:notice => 'Please register as a new user', :uid => 'ABCD'))
```

The params you want to pass are arguments to the `new_user_path` method, not the `redirect_to` method.